# ¿Es posible elegir una versión de .NET a utilizar en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, .net, vscode, net

Buen día, estoy con una duda referente al Visual Studio Code. Estaba en mis clases de universidad, tenía que crear un nuevo proyecto para una actividad, pero mientras usaba el comando `dotnet new console` tipico para uno en C#, este mismo me genero un error; el error lo conocía al tener el .NET 8.0 y no tener conexión a internet, pero el problema es que yo antes tenía el 7.0 funcionando correctamente.

Para dar algo de contexto a esto, tengo el Visual Studio para cierta materia, me instalo el .NET 8.0, pero no me generaba ese dilema con el Visual Studio Code, hasta los archivos los generaba con el .NET 7.0 sin problemas, pero esta vez como que se actualizo o similar, ya que ahora el Visual Studio Code utiliza el .NET 8.0.

Desearía saber si existe algún comando o similar que pueda crear proyectos en el Visual Studio Code eligiendo la versión a utilizar, sé que el Visual Studio tiene una opción para elegir la versión de .NET a utilizar, pero quisiera saber si es posible para el Visual Studio Code mediante comandos.

Y sí se preguntan por qué no desinstalo el .NET 8.0, es que no me deja al estar ligado al Visual Studio, por lo que no puedo desinstalarlo ya que de ley debo tenerlo igual para otras prácticas con otras materias.

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes. 2. Realiza el recorrido para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour 3. Lecturas recomendadas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación oficial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new

```
dotnet new <TEMPLATE> [--dry-run] [--force] [-lang|--language {"C#"|"F#"|VB}]
    [-n|--name <OUTPUT_NAME>] [-f|--framework <FRAMEWORK>] [--no-update-check]
    [-o|--output <OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>] [--project <PROJECT_PATH>]
    [-d|--diagnostics] [--verbosity <LEVEL>] [Template options]
```

Y considerando los "target framework moniker (TFM)"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

El comando sería

```
dotnet new console -f net7.0
```